# Inject CDI bean into Spring bean

Tags: spring, cdi

I have a `@RequestScoped` CDI bean and I would like to inject it into a spring bean. I already have beans.xml in META-INF. The stack error is this

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type XXX found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Also Spring scans the package in which I have declared the `@RequestScoped` bean.

Comment: The error means that Spring does not have a bean of the specified type XXX, so it cannot autowire it. Without more details it's hard to say what exactly is wrong.

Comment: It's kind of obvious, but why, because spring scans the package where that CDI bean is

Comment: Without more details (what does your XML look like? in what packages are the classes? what is XXX, what exactly does Spring not find and where? what version of Spring are you using?) we cannot tell you exactly why Spring doesn't find the bean.

Comment: I don't have a spring xml file, all the config is done by Configuration classes which scans packages and all other stuff specific to Configuration classes. XXX is the name of the class which is the @RequestScoped CDI bean. The package in which that XXX class resides is scaned by  the configuration class. Spring's version is 4.2.5

Comment: Do you only have the `@RequestScoped` annotation on that class? Spring only supports JSR-330 standard annotations, which doesn't include `@RequestScoped`. Have a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-standard-annotations

Comment: Yes, i only have the @RequestScoped annotation on that class.

Comment: Then you have to add a Spring annotation like `@Component` or maybe `@Controller` together with `@Scope("request")`.

Comment: I know but unfortunately, that @RequestScoped bean comes from a jar which I cannot change. I wanted to know if it is possible to inject it into a spring managed bean

Comment: Never tried anything like this but you might try creating a class that extends the class from the library and annotate it with `@Component` and then inject the subclass

Comment: Tried that, the injection works, but when i call getter methods from the super class it only return nulls.

Comment: If that class again has fields, which rely on CDI injection, then it doesn't work and you either have to use CDI for your project, or use another library.